# Include image in highcharts export

Tags: javascript, highcharts

As part of my chart there is a custom image in the bottom left corner of my chart with a company logo.  When I export the chart (pdf, png, etc) the image disappears.  Is there a way to make the image part of the export?

As an example, after defining the chart, I have this code snippet to add the image...

```
var chart = $('#my_chart').highcharts();
chart.renderer.image('/images/logo.gif',10,360,250,29).add();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this is so is because the state of the chart had changed after it was created. I would move your logo addition up to the [`chart.events.load`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.load) area like:

```
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function(event) {
                 this.renderer.image('/images/logo.gif',10,360,250,29).add();
            }
        }        
    }
```

Live [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9Evb6/).

Comment: What if I don't want it with chart but want it in exported file?

Comment: @HalfBloodPrince then add it to the chart.export options instead.